# Using -XX:HeapDumpPath option but want to integrate the process id

Tags: java, pid, heap-dump

When using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` the JVM will not overwrite the heap dump if there is already a dump file under the specified path. I want to be able to have multiple heap dumps in a non-default location, and was planning on using the pid in the heap dump path in order to allow that.

However, when I tried to specify the argument like so:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=some/heapdump/path/heapdump-%p.hprof
```

And then created a heap dump, I got `%p` and not the actual pid in the file name. However, the use of `%p` seems to work with the `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` option. Is there some other syntax that I'm supposed to use for `-XX:HeapDumpPath=`?

Answer (score 20):

That can be a path to a file OR directory. If you have a path to a directory, the generated file name will have pid in it by default.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: I am trying to do "some stuff" ONLY if there is a directory /path/to/heapdump present/exists. What happens when the path provided in /path/to/heapdump does not exist but is set in HeapDumpPath? On OOME, does jvm create the path and then create the heapdump at that path?

Answer (score 2):

You should add which Java you use. These options depends on the JVM vendor (IBM, Oracle, etc.)

**OnOutOfMemoryError** says WHEN to perform the dump. **HeapDumpPath** says WHERE to put the dump. I think the use of HeapDumpPath turns on the first, but I advice to use both for clarity.

About the original question, use the pid in the dump file name is a good practice. It can help in particular to corolate and analyse what happens after multiple issues/restarts.

The exact syntax is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html).